# measures on the Borel field generated by a field.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu,\nu$ be two measures defined on the same Borel field
>   $\mathcal F$ generated by the field $\mathcal F_0$. If $\mu$ is
>   $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal F_0$, and $\mu(E)=\nu(E)$ for every
>   $E\in\mathcal F_0$, then the same is true for every $E\in\mathcal F$,
>   and thus $\mu=\nu$.

This is a theorem in Kai Lai Chung's *A Course in Probability Theory*, and he gives a proof when $\mu$ is finite:

> Let $\mathcal C=\{E\in\mathcal F\mid \mu(E)=\nu(E)\}$, then $\mathcal
> > F_0\subset\mathcal C$. But $\mathcal C$ is also a monotone class, for
>   if $E_n\in\mathcal C$, $E_n\uparrow E$ or $E_n\downarrow E$, then
>   $\mu(E)=\lim_n\mu(E_n)=\lim_n\nu(E_n)=\nu(E)$. Hence, 
>   $F\subset\mathcal C$.

Now I want to prove the theorem when $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. I'm considering the same $\mathcal C$, and trying to prove it is a monotone class. When $E_n\uparrow E$, the argument is the same. It seems that $\sigma$-finiteness is crucial when $E_n\downarrow E$, for without this restriction $\mu(E)=\lim_n\mu(E_n)$ can be false.

How can I go on? Or is the general case follows directly from the special one?

Note: The theorem is similar to the uniqueness of Carathéodory's extension. Since the latter has different versions, I'm not sure if this theorem follows directly from that, especially we only know $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal F_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mu$ is $\sigma$ finite w.r.t. $F_0$, we can write $X=\bigcup X_n$ with $X_n \subset X_{n+1}$ and $\mu(X_n)<\infty$ (this also uses that $F_0$ is a field).

Now verify that the **finite** measures $\mu_n (M) := \mu (X_n \cap M)$ and $\nu_n. (M):=\nu(X_n\cap M)$ satisfy your requirements (that again uses that $F_0$ is a field).

Finally, conclude $\mu(M) =\lim \mu (M\cap X_n) =\lim \nu(M\cap X_n)=\nu(M)$.

Comment: Does $X$ mean $\mathcal F$?

Comment: @EclipseSun: $X$ is the set over which $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra. You did not mention that set. Sometimes, this base set is also  called $\Omega$.